# how to kill sleep process and chain thread

Tags: linux

I'm running a chain command sleep 300; wget some-page;

and I want to kill the sleep and wget, but what's happening is the wget is still firing off when I kill the sleep pid.

TY

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Change your command to be

```
sleep 300 && wget some-page
```

This will only run the wget command if sleep exits with a 0 status. When the sleep is killed it exits with a non zero status so the `&&` the next command not to run.

Comment: That worked!

ty so much